# Android Spinner not updating with JSON data Volley

Tags: android, json, spinner, android-volley

For the following code I am using [MultiSelectSpinner](https://github.com/wongk/MultiSelectSpinner)

So I am trying to update a spinner with JSON location data and it wont update for some reason even when I put it inside onCreate. I know that I'm parsing the JSON correctly because when I ask toast to print out the locations I'm getting I correctly get each and every location. Therefore I think the problem lies when I create my MultiSelectSpinner and try to setItems. However, the MultiSelectSpinner class has a constructor for setting items with a String list so I'm puzzled. I would love to know if anyone spots any glaring errors or has any advice. I've also tried to use ArrayAdapter with no luck.

```
private List<String> locationList = new LinkedList<String>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_buyer_profile_edit);
        SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

        RequestQueue mRequestQueue;
        Cache cache = new DiskBasedCache(getCacheDir(), 1024 * 1024);

        Network network = new BasicNetwork(new HurlStack());
        final List<String> locationsProvided = new LinkedList<String>();
        mRequestQueue = new RequestQueue(cache, network);
        mRequestQueue.start();

        final String locationURL = "http://10.0.2.2:3000/apip/locations";
        // Testing for Valid JSON Web Token
        mRequestQueue.add(new JsonArrayRequest(locationURL,
                new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                        try {
                            for(int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                                JSONObject locObj = response.getJSONObject(i);
                                String location = locObj.getString("location");
                                locationList.add(location);
                                Toast.makeText(BuyerProfileEdit.this,location,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                error.printStackTrace();
            }
        }));

        MultiSelectSpinner mySpin = (MultiSelectSpinner)findViewById(R.id.locationDropDownBuyer);
        mySpin.setItems(locationList);


        Button saveProfile =  (Button) findViewById(R.id.submitProfile);

        saveProfile.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                updateBuyerProfile();
            }
        });


    }
```

Edit: After moving my setItems(locationList) to right after I parse the data inside of onResponse, it works perfectly!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move `setItems` just after parsing all data

```
try {
                            for(int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                                JSONObject locObj = response.getJSONObject(i);
                                String location = locObj.getString("location");
                                locationList.add(location);
                                Toast.makeText(BuyerProfileEdit.this,location,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                           MultiSelectSpinner mySpin = (MultiSelectSpinner)findViewById(R.id.locationDropDownBuyer);
        mySpin.setItems(locationList);
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
```

Comment: Yes!! Thank you. Been stuck on this for a day. Works flawlessly now.

Comment: of course! Had to wait a little before Stackoverflow allowed me to mark it but I just did. Thank you once again!

Comment: @DavidParks Best of luck for future